# How to add security for Java Melody Monitor URL in spring application

Tags: java, spring, servlets, java-melody

We are using `Java Melody` in spring application. I would like to add security to access `/monitoring` url only by admin user. I have to check some property value and permissions based on that one should get access.

What are the different approaches available to achieve this? Can we do it in spring security?

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information here.

Comment: If you only need some one or some ip can login. I suggest using aop or interceptor.

Comment: Only user which has admin permissions.

Comment: @石荒人  Could you give me some example on interceptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javamelody parameters `authorized-users` for http basic auth or `allowed-addr-pattern` for access based on ip address.
See https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#16-security

For example in application.yml, if you use Spring-boot:

```yml
javamelody:
  init-parameters:
    authorized-users: admin:password
```

Or you can use Spring security with `.antMatchers("/monitoring").hasRole("ADMIN")`.

For example in Spring-boot 2, using spring-boot-starter-security dependency, basic auth and in memory user's storage:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/monitoring").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password")
                .roles("USER").build();
        UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("password")
                .roles("ADMIN").build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }
}
```

If you use Spring security without Spring boot, be sure to put the Spring Security filter before the javamelody Monitoring filter in your web.xml file.